# how to expand a youtube thumbnail on load using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, youtube-javascript-api

i got a solution for my question from [how to get rid of youtube videos getting repeated even though different embedded code is given?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932091/how-to-get-rid-of-youtube-videos-getting-repeated-even-though-different-embedded) link. i have a small requirement which is i have to resize  my youtube video thumbnail image in to width:146px and height:124px on the page on load event. please help me to attain this. thanks in advance.

here is the link for youtube videos imported on a page which will expand on click

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932091/how-to-get-rid-of-youtube-videos-getting-repeated-even-though-different-embedded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube API can only output images in 120x90 or 480x360 pixels.

For example (video from your jsFiddle):

- http://img.youtube.com/vi/Cgovv8jWETM/0.jpg - 480x360
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/Cgovv8jWETM/1.jpg = 120x90
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/Cgovv8jWETM/2.jpg = 120x90
- http://img.youtube.com/vi/Cgovv8jWETM/3.jpg = 120x90

Why don't you just modify the height and width of the thumbnail image in your HTML on the `img` tag?

Comment: @krishnamoorthy If I've helped. It would be appreciated if you ticked my response as correct. :-)